# How flex AS3.0 remove the Listener?

Tags: apache-flex

I want to remove the listener, but it can not be removed. I use the method: board.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseDrag);

```
var board:UIComponent=new UIComponent();
board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, function(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                mouseDrag(event,board);             
            });

private function mouseDrag(event:MouseEvent,board:UIComponent):void
        {
            var x:Number=rectX + (event.stageX - mouseX);
            var y:Number=rectY + (event.stageY - mouseY);               board.x=x;
            board.y=y;      
        }
```

How flex AS3.0 remove the Listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not removing the same function as the one you attached in the first place. You attached an anonymous function that executes `mouseDrag` and you're trying to remove `mouseDrag` itself.

There are a few solutions to your situation.

### 1. Ditch the anonymous function and use event.currentTarget

```
board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseDrag);
private function mouseDrag(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var board:UIComponent = event.currentTarget as UIComponent;
    board.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseDrag);
    ...
}
```

### 2. Put the anonymous function in a variable so you have a reference

```
var anonymousFunction:Function = function(event:MouseEvent):void {
    mouseDrag(event,board);             
};
board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, anonymousFunction);
```

You can now remove the listener correctly if you still have access to that reference:

```
board.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, anonymousFunction);
```